# Change WooCommerce validation text when adding grouped products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

Want to change the WooCommerce text Please choose a product to add to your cart… for when adding grouped products to the cart.

I see it here - see below - but I would like to create a snippet code that I can add to my custom functions instead of touching the code.

```
/**
     * Handle adding grouped products to the cart.
     *
     * @since 2.4.6 Split from add_to_cart_action.
     * @param int $product_id Product ID to add to the cart.
     * @return bool success or not
     */
    private static function add_to_cart_handler_grouped( $product_id ) {
        $was_added_to_cart = false;
        $added_to_cart     = array();
        $items             = isset( $_REQUEST['quantity'] ) && is_array( $_REQUEST['quantity'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['quantity'] ) : array(); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.NonceVerification.Recommended, WordPress.Security.ValidatedSanitizedInput.InputNotSanitized

        if ( ! empty( $items ) ) {
            $quantity_set = false;

            foreach ( $items as $item => $quantity ) {
                $quantity = wc_stock_amount( $quantity );
                if ( $quantity <= 0 ) {
                    continue;
                }
                $quantity_set = true;

                // Add to cart validation.
                $passed_validation = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $item, $quantity );

                // Suppress total recalculation until finished.
                remove_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', array( WC()->cart, 'calculate_totals' ), 20, 0 );

                if ( $passed_validation && false !== WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $item, $quantity ) ) {
                    $was_added_to_cart      = true;
                    $added_to_cart[ $item ] = $quantity;
                }

                add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', array( WC()->cart, 'calculate_totals' ), 20, 0 );
            }

            if ( ! $was_added_to_cart && ! $quantity_set ) {
                wc_add_notice( __( 'Please choose the quantity of items you wish to add to your cart…', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            } elseif ( $was_added_to_cart ) {
                wc_add_to_cart_message( $added_to_cart );
                WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
                return true;
            }
        } elseif ( $product_id ) {
            /* Link on product archives */
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Please choose a product to add to your cart…', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I am not good at this custom code, but I would like to add my own custom message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter('gettext_woocommerce', 'translate_woocommerce_strings_cart');

function translate_woocommerce_strings_cart($string) {

    if ('Please choose a product to add to your cart&hellip;' === $string) {
        $string = esc_html__('Please choose a product.', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $string;
}
```